# Gnuplot using stats in for loop

Tags: statistics, gnuplot, ntp

i wanna plot the maximum and average value of different files into one plot.
I got several ntp-stats, so i thought:

```
input = "./peerstats/s_peerstats.201407"
set terminal svg size 600 400
set xlabel "Day in July (s)"
set ylabel "Jitter (ms)"
set yrange[0:0.65]

set output "ntpq_month_07.svg"
do for [k=10:31]{
    stats input.k."_pps" using ($8*1000.0) nooutput name "PPS",\
    stats input.k."_rz1" using ($8*1000.0) nooutput name "RZ1",\
    stats input.k."_rz2" using ($8*1000.0) nooutput name "RZ2",\
    set "ntpq_month_07.svg" 
    print ($k):PPS_max
    print ($k):RZ1_max
    print ($k):RZ2_max
    print ($k):PPS_mean
    print ($k):RZ1_mean 
    print ($k):RZ2_mean
}
```

This is the error by gnuplot:

```
    ;
    stats input.k."_pps" using ($8*1000.0) nooutput name "PPS", stats input.k."_rz1" using ($8*1000.0) nooutput name "RZ1", stats input.k."_rz2" using ($8*1000.0) nooutput name "RZ2", set "ntpq_month_07.svg" ;
    print ($k):PPS_max;
    print ($k):RZ1_max;
    print ($k):RZ2_max;
    print ($k):PPS_mean;
    print ($k):RZ1_mean ;
    print ($k):RZ2_mean;

                                                          ^
line 20: Expecting [no]output or prefix
```

Where is the syntax wrong?

Thanks a lot :)!

Comment: Try getting rid of the `,\` at the end of the `stats` lines. I am also not sure whether your `print` command will work--I am not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: I've tried this, but it wont work :(

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: New error is: line 19: Column number expected, where line 19 is the closing brace

Comment: It doesn't work to have the stats commands on three separate lines (no commas separating them)? If you try reducing your loop to a single stats command (no printing) does that work?

Comment: If I reduce the example above (removing loop statement and all k-indices, so that there is print PPS_max....), the script will run finde , but output.svg is not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must have all `stats` commands on a separate line. That works fine. Then it is your `print` syntax which is broken.

Consider the file `test.dat`

```
1
2
```

and the call

```
do for [i=10:11] {
    stats 'test.dat' using 1 nooutput name "PPS"
    stats 'test.dat' using ($1*i) nooutput name "RZ1"
    print sprintf("max(PPS_%d): %f", i, PPS_max)
    print sprintf("max(RZ1_%d): %f", i, RZ1_max)
}
```

gives the output

```
max(PPS_10): 2.000000
max(RZ1_10): 20.000000
max(PPS_11): 2.000000
max(RZ1_11): 22.000000
```

So your script should look as follows:

```
input = "./peerstats/s_peerstats.201407"
set terminal svg size 600 400
set xlabel "Day in July (s)"
set ylabel "Jitter (ms)"
set yrange[0:0.65]

set output "ntpq_month_07.svg"
do for [k=10:31]{
    stats input.k."_pps" using ($8*1000.0) nooutput name "PPS"
    stats input.k."_rz1" using ($8*1000.0) nooutput name "RZ1"
    stats input.k."_rz2" using ($8*1000.0) nooutput name "RZ2"
    set "ntpq_month_07.svg" 
    print sprintf('%d: %f', k, PPS_max)
    print sprintf('%d: %f', k, RZ1_max)
    print sprintf('%d: %f', k, RZ2_max)
    print sprintf('%d: %f', k, PPS_mean)
    print sprintf('%d: %f', k, RZ1_mean)
    print sprintf('%d: %f', k, RZ2_mean)
}
```

Of course your svg files don't contain any output, because you don't plot anything.

Comment: Awesome, a tutorial like this was missing in the web. Thanks :)